# Android - add default value in GreenDao database

Tags: android, greendao

I would like to ask, if there is possibility to add default value when I create greenDao database?

```
Example:
Property pictureIdProperty = user.addLongProperty("pictureId").getProperty();
Property thumbnailIdProperty = user.addLongProperty("thumbnailId").getProperty();
//and here I need something like this:
//thumbnailIdProperty.setDefault(-1); //there is possible to add 
user.addToOne(picture, pictureIdProperty);
user.addToOne(picture, thumbnailIdProperty, "thumbnail");
```

And when I'm using database and this table then there is no need to add default value always when I create this model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe there is any official support by the GreenDAO project for this as of today but I have an idea. Sqlite supports the [DEFAULT](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) table constraint which can be applied to a column. For [example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp), the code block below shows the default value for the `City` column in table `Persons` is 'Sandnes'.

```
    CREATE TABLE Persons
    (
      P_Id int NOT NULL,
      LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      FirstName varchar(255),
      Address varchar(255),
      City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Sandnes'
    )
```

Knowing sqlite supports the `Default` constraint, we can hack the generated `DAO` class. I'll use [OrderDAO.java](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/465e2ef056ce2d9b5362e51bdffff8ba6bd0ed64/DaoExample/src-gen/de/greenrobot/daoexample/OrderDao.java) as an example. The below snippet is the GreenDAO generated code `create table` code block:

```
    public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifNotExists) {
        String constraint = ifNotExists? "IF NOT EXISTS ": "";
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + constraint + "'ORDERS' (" + //
               "'_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + // 0: id
               "'DATE' INTEGER," + // 1: date
               "'CUSTOMER_ID' INTEGER NOT NULL );"); // 2: customerId
    }
```

Now we can *most likely* modify this to support the `DEFUALT` constraint. Change last relevant line in the above code block by adding `DEFAULT(-1)`.

```
    "'CUSTOMER_ID' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT(-1));"); // 2: customerId
```

Note: When testing this change, make sure to either increment your sqlite schema version or re-install your app so the database gets recreated.

Comment: This won't work very well as DAO will recreate the *Dao.java class and reset the changes.