# greenDAO String length constraint

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I'm trying to force a certain limitation regarding the length of a string in my database model using greenDAO. I would have guessed something like this exists:

```
protected void addProperties(Schema inSchema, Entity inEntity) {
        inEntity.addIdProperty();
        inEntity.addStringProperty("description").notNull().maxLength(42);
    }
```

My first guess then was to alter the resulting DAO-class (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19230102/2408700) for another purpose), like this:

```
public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifNotExists) {
    String constraint = ifNotExists? "IF NOT EXISTS ": "";
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + constraint + "'TEST' (" + //
           "'_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + 
           "'DESCRIPTION' VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL );");
}
```

Then I found that SQLite does not even support the limitation of strings by itself:

> "SQLite does not enforce the length of a VARCHAR. You can declare a VARCHAR(10) and SQLite will be happy to let you put 500 characters in it. And it will keep all 500 characters intact - it never truncates." from [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9)

The only (ugly) solution I could come up with was to write another wrapper for the DAO-Object. So my question is: Is there any elegant solution for what I'm trying to archieve and/ or are there any plans to include it in a future release of greenDAO?

Comment: I believe you are stuck implementing the string length enforcement logic yourself. As you said in your post, sqlite will not enforce it and greenDAO does not provide that functionality either. I'd say your solution is the best option.

Comment: I'd suggest you to open an issue into GreenDao repo in order to suggest this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are no plans to integrate such constraints in greendao.
So the most elegant solution would be to write a feature for greendao. This way you can put your constraint definition where it belongs: Your (greendao-)schema.

You'd have to modify `de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Property` and add something like this:

```
private Integer textLength = null;

public static class PropertyBuilder {
    ...
    public PropertyBuilder length(int length) {
        if (property.propertyType != PropertyType.String) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This is only supported for text!");
        }
        if (length <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        property.textLength = length;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then you could either check if the Strings that get set on the entity match your constraint and throw an exception on the corresponding setter by modifying `entity.ftl` so that the setter includes your condition.
This could be bypassed by adding new methods in the keep sections to the entity.

Your second option would be to modify `dao.ftl` the `bindValues`-method to include your condition. This way the bypass is closed (although there are still other possibilities to bypass this).

Comment: Thanks for your insight of GreenDao. While I did not implement your suggestion (see answer below), I'll still accept it since it promises to do exactly what I was originally asking for. 
I went with the wrapper class though, because it greatly helped to keep track of the database operations and made them reusable and somehow semantic.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestions and sorry for not answering. I ended up implemeting a wrapper class for the DAO-Objects, which was not such a bad idea after all.
As illustrated below, an Activity can instantiate a specific Database-Service which uses a DAO-Object to alter the database's content. The service provides methods which comply with the business logic and thus validate data before they are written into the database.

[image: Activity not using the DAO-Object directly but by an interposed Database-Service]

Comment: Nice and elegant solution. This way you are even capable of enforcing restrictions over more than one table if needed. But I would have liked the constraint-feature for greendao. Maybe later on.